# Solaris11 back to console boot

Tags: solaris, runlevel

I installed Solaris 11 X86.
I installed `solaris-desktop`.

Then Solaris boots to GUI mode.

How can I make the Solaris boots to console mode? (And then optionally starts X by hand?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable booting into the GUI by running the following command:

```
svcadm disable application/graphical-login/gdm:default
```

This will disable the GUI until you re enable the service.

Comment: After disabling the gdm service, you can start X by hand via the `startx` command (to run as the user who runs startx), or by temporarily re-enabling the gdm service to offer a login screen to choose which user to run X as.